# Attach content type to task list

Tags: workflow, content-type, task-list

I have created a content type that inherits directly from the "workflow task" content type. I deployed it as a feature and activated it. Now, I want to attach it to the "Task" list in a site, but when I select "Add from existing site content types" the custom content type is not available. I even moved it to the List Content Types group since the custom group was not an option. Here is my content type:

```
  <ContentType Name="Item Checklist _x0023_5 _x0028_Procurement_x0029_" 
ID="0x01080100B013991EFD9C4686A5FF33D3B6567138"
Group="CCMS" 
Hidden="FALSE"
Description="Type N/A if not applicable">
<FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef ID="{A362E8DF-614E-4C56-BDC9-06244CE6C03E}" DisplayName="Customer Requirements Met" Description="" Name="Customer_x0020_Requirements_x002"/>
    <FieldRef ID="{03C0A44F-ED73-46FD-B847-2663217BE643}" DisplayName="Material Requirement Review" Description="" Name="Material_x0020_Requirement_x00201"/>
</FieldRefs>
```

Comment: "I have created a content type" how and where?

Comment: It was created in notepad and put it in the 12 hive. I installed it using stsadm. It appears in SP as a content type, I just can't associate it with the task list. It is almost as if it is the wrong "type" or something, making it unavailable to the task list.